# Linq to SQL and MVC 2 "Class member MyClass.MyProperty is unmapped. _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

Thanks in advance for listening to my problem.

I have a Linq to Sql Class, for which specific properties are being displayed on a Grid for which I use a ViewModel.

Firstly i'll paste the part where I extentend my class via a partial class:

```
    public string Owner { get; private set; }
    public Int32 Documents { get; private set; }

    partial void OnLoaded()
    {
        Owner = "PersonCompanyRoleMedicalExam";
        Documents = sfdb.StoredFiles.Count(s => s.Owner == this.Owner && s.OwnerId == this.Id);
    }
```

Next ill paste my ViewModel used for the Grid:

```
public class MedicalExamViewModel
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 PersonCompanyRoleId { get; set; }
    public Int32? PeriodInDays { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExamCompleted { get; set; }
    public bool? MedicallyFit { get; set; }
    public Int32 Documents { get; set; }
}
```

and then lastly my method for an ajax call from my grid to populate it:

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _MedicalExamGridAjaxBinding(Int32 Id)
    {
        PersonCompanyRole personCompanyRole = db.PersonCompanyRoles.Single(p => p.PersonId == Id);

        var model = from o in db.PersonCompanyRoleMedicalExams
                    where o.PersonCompanyRoleId == personCompanyRole.Id
                    select new MedicalExamViewModel
                    {
                        Id = o.Id,
                        PersonCompanyRoleId = o.PersonCompanyRoleId,
                        PeriodInDays = o.PeriodInDays,
                        ExamCompleted = o.ExamCompleted,
                        MedicallyFit = o.MedicallyFit,
                        Documents = o.Documents
                    };

        return View(new GridModel
        {
            Data = model
        });
    }
```

On the line "var model = from o in db.PersonCompanyRoleMedicalExams" where I break just after, looking at the object i get base {System.SystemException} = {"Class member PersonCompanyRoleSHEAppointment.Documents is unmapped."}

Digging in deeper into the object into the exception which is System.SystemException, in the InnerException it states the following: _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766 .

The funny thing is that I use the exact same technique to populate other objects / models in my project without any problems, there is one difference though, and that is that there is a linking table in between. Something like this: Person -> PersonCompanyRole > PersonCompanyRoleMedicalExam. Person to PersonCompanyRole is a one-to-one relationship and PersonCompanyRole to PersonCompanyRoleMedicalExam is a one-to-many. For completeness ill paste in my ajax method where i dont get any exceptions.

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _IncidentsGridAjaxBinding(Int32 Id)
    {
        var structures = db.sp_GetCompanyStructureDecendants(Id);
        Collection<CompanyStructureIncident> companyStructureIncidents = new Collection<CompanyStructureIncident>();

        foreach (sp_GetCompanyStructureDecendantsResult decendant in structures)
        {
            IEnumerable<CompanyStructureIncident> equipment = db.CompanyStructureIncidents.Where(r => r.CompanyStructureId == decendant.Id);
            foreach (CompanyStructureIncident companyStructureIncident in equipment)
            {
                companyStructureIncidents.Add(db.CompanyStructureIncidents.Single(p => p.Id == companyStructureIncident.Id));
            }
        }



        var model = from o in companyStructureIncidents
                    //where o.CompanyStructureId == Id
                    select new IncidentViewModel
                    {
                        Id = o.Id,
                        CompanyStructureId = o.CompanyStructureId,
                        DateOfOccurence = o.DateOfOccurence,
                        DateReported = o.DateReported,
                        Documents = o.Documents
                    };

        return View(new GridModel
        {
            Data = model
        });
    }
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, instead of using OnLoad() I do this:

```
    public string Owner
    {
        get { return "PersonCompanyRoleMedicalExam"; }
    }

    public Int32 Documents
    {
        get { return sfdb.StoredFiles.Count(s => s.Owner == this.Owner && s.OwnerId == this.Id); }
    }
```

Thanks anyways, hope this will help someone else.